# Select where clause = label.text why not working

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

**This is the code**

```
    Call Connects()
    Label3.Text = Dummy2
    MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand
    MySqlCmd.Connection = Myconnect
    MySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from montibill.order_sub where Os_Number=" & Dummy2 & ""
    MyDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
    myDataTable = New DataTable
    MyDA.SelectCommand = MySqlCmd
    MyDA.Fill(myDataTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable
```

the code only show the tables but the values did not show i dont know why please  help

Comment: are you sure that `Myconnect` connected? check your target host / username / password first.

Comment: nothing wrong with using a text box to take a value, but you should really be using parametrised queries for security - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes all works  when i change my  where clause = 1 it work
but when i pass it to may dummy2  it doesnt work
by the way i try to make it double and integer and doesnt work

Comment: are you sure that varible Dummy2 is not empty, and the data requested exists in the table? that should work if the value exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your pic enclosed, where the variable Dummy2 comes from ? it doesnt declared in that function, is that variable declared as global ?

please check the Dummy2 valued first.

Comment: im analayzing it wait again

Answer (score 0):

use single comma in place of double

```
"Select * from montibill.order_sub where Os_Number=' & Dummy2 &'"
```

Comment: and you sure that would run? notice the double quotes on the start and the end, while you put the variable Dummy2 inside it.

Comment: it doesnt work  the   & dummy2 & still in orange not in black means not it use?